# Perl : Perform syntax check of perl module before re-load

Tags: perl, reload, perl-module

How can we perform a syntax check , before we try to load the perl module dynamically?

We push DIV rendering Perl modules , and have written a re-load module that loads these Perl modules based on modification time stamp.

And would like to incorporate a quick compilation check on these perl modules ( something similar to perl -wc ) , to see that the module to be re-loaded is all good to be re-loaded.

Comment: [`perl -c`](http://p3rl.org/run#*-c*) **is** already the syntax check.

Answer (score 3):

[`syntax_ok` in `Test::Strict`](http://p3rl.org/Test%3a%3aStrict#syntax_ok-file-text) provides a wrapper around `perl -c` for arbitrary Perl code in a file.

[`require_ok`/`use_ok` in `Test::More`](http://p3rl.org/Test%3a%3aMore#use_ok) do something similar for modules.